# why does while() loop not work on pathTransition?

Tags: javafx

I've been trying to make my pathTransition loop but it doesn't work. I have already tried with a while loop but nothing happens. "boom" runs the path once and then stops. I would like the "boom" to choose a new path each time.

```
    int i = 1;
    while(i < 5){
        Path path = new Path();
        double x = (new Random().ints(-100,400 + 1).iterator().next());
        path.getElements().add (new MoveTo (x, -190));
        path.getElements().add (new LineTo(x, 300));

        PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
        pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(10000));
        pathTransition.setNode(boom);
        pathTransition.setPath(path);
        pathTransition.setOrientation(OrientationType.NONE);
        pathTransition.setAutoReverse(false);
        pathTransition.play();
        i++;
```

Comment: You're creating four different transitions for the same node and playing them all simultaneously. If you want one after the other, put them all in a [`SequentialTransition`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html) and play the `SequentialTransition`.

Comment: This seems like you'll end up with multiple transitions working at the same time. Maybe you want to start one after the other has finished?

Comment: so if I use the sequentialTransition would it create a new path?

Comment: and yes Matt I want to start another "boom" after the other has finished.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add all your PathTransitions to a SequentialTransition like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.SequentialTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class PathLoop extends Application {
    Node boom;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button goButton = new Button("Go");
        goButton.setOnAction(this::doAnimation);
        boom = new Circle(20, Color.RED);
        AnchorPane playfield = new AnchorPane(boom);
        playfield.setPrefSize(600, 600);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(boom, 100.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(boom, 300.0);
        VBox root = new VBox(goButton, playfield);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sequential Transition");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    private void doAnimation(ActionEvent e) {
        Random rng = new Random();
        SequentialTransition seqTransition = new SequentialTransition(boom);
        int i = 1;
        while(i < 5){
            Path path = new Path();
            double x = (rng.ints(-100,400 + 1).iterator().next());
            path.getElements().add (new MoveTo(x, -190));
            path.getElements().add (new LineTo(x, 300));

            PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
            pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(10000));
            pathTransition.setNode(boom);
            pathTransition.setPath(path);
            pathTransition.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.NONE);
            pathTransition.setAutoReverse(false);
            seqTransition.getChildren().add(pathTransition);
            i++;
        }
        seqTransition.play();
    }

}
```